# create anchors dynamically with in para

Tags: javascript, html

I'm writing a javascript program that gets the input in any of the below forms.

```
"Here is the result \"<a href=\"www.google.com\">google</a>\", and \"<a href=\"www.yahoo.com\">yahoo</a>\""
```

or

```
"Here is a plain result"
```

and this is stored in a variable say X. and I want to create an anchor tag when ever I come across an anchor tag. I know that `a href` will by default create an anchor tag but in my case the result is rendered as a text, here is my code that I've tried so far.

```
var newLink = document.createElement('a');
newLink.href = 'http://google.com';
newLink.innerHTML = 'My anchor';

if (message) {
    var x = message;
    console.log(x.includes("href"));
    if (!x.includes("href")) {
        responsePara.appendChild(document.createTextNode(message));
        responsePara.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
    } else {
        //responsePara.appendChild(document.createTextNode(message));
        responsePara.appendChild(newLink);
        responsePara.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
    }
}
```

the output that I'm expecting is in **case 1**

```
<p> Here is the result "<a href="www.google.com">google</a>", and "<a href="www.yahoo.com">yahoo</a>"</p>
```

**in case 2**

```
<p>Here is a plain result</p>
```

please let me know on how can I do this.

**Note** I'm using only js, no *jquery*

Answer (score 0):

I can't see your problem, it should be really easy to implement this, right?

**All you need to parse is the input that is coming to HTML. within another element 
 (in your case `p` element)**

## UPDATE

I have updated this question, so you can modify (or create if there is not `ref`) an existing element with not parsed `a` element or with plain text.

```js
function createOrUpdateCompositeLink(input, ref) {
  if (ref) {
    var isLinkText = input.match(/href/g);
    var elementChild;

    if (isLinkText) {
      elementChild = document.createElement('span');
      elementChild.innerHTML = input;
    } else {
      elementChild = document.createTextNode(input);
    }
    
    ref.appendChild(elementChild);

    return ref;
  } else {
    var element = document.createElement('p');

    element.innerHTML = input;  
    return element;
  }
}


/* USAGE */
var message;
var element;

message  = "Here is the result ";
message1 = "<a href=\"www.google.com\">google</a>\"";
message2 = " something plain text ";
message3 = ", and \"<a href=\"www.yahoo.com\">yahoo</a>\"";


var reference = document.querySelector('.ref');
var el;

createOrUpdateCompositeLink(message, reference);
createOrUpdateCompositeLink(message1, reference);
createOrUpdateCompositeLink(message2, reference);
createOrUpdateCompositeLink(message3, reference);
```

```html
<div class="ref"></div>
```

Comment: How am I supposed to add an anchor tag?, the data gets rendered as a plain text

Comment: Do you want to add extra "not-parsed" HTML to a parsed element? is that your point ?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you consider using jQuery and what you are trying to do becomes:

```
jQuery(".response").append(message);
```

I assume that your `responsePara` variable is defined from an existing `<div>` somewhere. In my example, that `<div>` would have a class named `response`.

```
<div class="response"></div>
```

Once you get a message, it gets added to the response `div` but that one line `jQuery()` command.